# bootstrap-sass gem breaking my rails 3.2.3 at step 5.1.2 in Hartl's rails tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

Everything up to this point has worked great, including upload to github and heroku, as well as using postgres for dev/test and prod/heroku.

As soon as I add

> gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.0.0'

to my Gemfile and run `bundle install` (or `bundle install --without assets`), spork, guard, and rails (and stand-alone passenger) all complain w/ the following:

```
/var/lib/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:74:in `require': cannot load such file -- bootstrap/sass (LoadError)
    from /var/lib/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:74:in `rescue in block in require'
    from /var/lib/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:62:in `block in require'
    from /var/lib/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
    from /var/lib/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
    from /var/lib/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler.rb:119:in `require'
    from /var/lib/rails/sample_app/config/application.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
    from /var/lib/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /var/lib/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

here's my Gemfile and the relevant part of Gemfile.lock:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.3'
gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.0.0'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.0.1'
#gem 'faker', '1.0.1'
#gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.3'
#gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.5'

group :development, :test do
  #gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.9.0'
  gem 'guard-rspec', '0.5.5'
end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '3.2.4'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
  gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
  #gem 'factory_girl_rails', '1.4.0'
  #gem 'cucumber-rails', '1.2.1', require: false
  #gem 'database_cleaner', '0.7.0'
  gem 'guard-spork', '0.3.2'
        gem 'spork', '0.9.0'
        # gem 'rb-fsevent', '0.4.3.1', require: false
        # gem 'growl', '1.0.3'
end

#group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
#end
```

$ egrep "bootstrap|sass" Gemfile.lock

```
bootstrap-sass (2.0.0)
sass (3.1.17)
sass-rails (3.2.4)
  sass (>= 3.1.10)
bootstrap-sass (= 2.0.0)
sass-rails (= 3.2.4)
```

the platform is a Gentoo OpenVZ container, using a dedicated, non-privileged 'rails' account.

I've checked my work several times, removed gems and re-bundled, still no love.

Answer (score 2):

try putting bootstrap-sass in the assets group of the Gemfile?

```
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
  gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.0.2'
end
```

Comment: thanks, house9, I think that got me to the next error.  ;^)  now I'm getting this: `ActionView::Template::Error (cannot load such file -- sass
  (in /var/lib/rails/sample_app/app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss)):`