# Could not find gem 'bootstrap-sass (= 2.3.2.0) ruby' (Step 5.1.2 in railtutorial.org)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, railstutorial.org

Searched high and low... found similar problems, but none of the fixes have helped... Does anyone have an idea of what to try next?

I am following [Railstutorial.org 5.1.2](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/filling-in-the-layout#sec-custom_css) and after installing bootstrap-sass gem, I get the following after restarting apache:

```
Could not find bootstrap-sass-2.3.2.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
  /home/bart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in `block in materialize'
  /home/bart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `map!'
  /home/bart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `materialize'
  /home/bart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:114:in `specs'
  /home/bart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:159:in `specs_for'
  /home/bart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:148:in `requested_specs'
  /home/bart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/environment.rb:18:in `requested_specs'
  /home/bart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13:in `setup'
  /home/bart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `setup'
  /home/bart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/setup.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/bart/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:133:in `require'
  /home/bart/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:133:in `rescue in require'
  /home/bart/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:142:in `require'
  /home/bart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/passenger-4.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:212:in `run_load_path_setup_code'
  /home/bart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/passenger-4.0.19/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:96:in `preload_app'
  /home/bart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/passenger-4.0.19/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:150:in `<module:App>'
  /home/bart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/passenger-4.0.19/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /home/bart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/passenger-4.0.19/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:28:in `<main>'
```

Bootstrap is installed... (tried version 2.3.2.0 as well)

```
bart:/var/www/sample_app$ bundle | grep bootstrap
Using bootstrap-sass (2.3.2.2)
```

and

```
bart:/var/www/sample_app$ bundle show bootstrap
/home/bart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/bootstrap-sass-2.3.2.2
```

Similar issues have been resolved with putting the gem bootstrap-sass into the :asset group in the Gemfile - that didn't help. (e.g., [almost exact same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10564977/bootstrap-sass-gem-breaking-my-rails-3-2-3-at-step-5-1-2-in-hartls-rails-tutori))

```
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.0'
  gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.0'
  gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.3.2.0'
end
```

I actually just added the bcrypt-ruby-3.1.2 gem earlier in the Gemfile and that gave the same problem...

I skipped the end of Ch3 (all of 3.6) where there is a lot more about testing, so maybe I missed a step in there somewhere, but everything in there appeared optional.

Others mention to do a

```
rake gem
```

or
    rake gemspec
but I get something like this for both:

```
bart:/var/www/sample_app$ bundle exec rake gemspec --trace
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'gemspec'
```

and haven't figured out what that exactly means yet.

More details:

```
bart:/var/www/sample_app$ rvm info
ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0:

  system:
    uname:       "Linux 452422 3.2.0-38-generic #61-Ubuntu SMP Tue Feb 19 12:18:21 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux"
    system:      "ubuntu/12.04/x86_64"
    bash:        "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 4.2.24(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)"
    zsh:         " => not installed"

  rvm:
    version:      "rvm 1.22.15 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]"
    updated:      "1 day 6 hours 36 minutes 3 seconds ago"
    path:         "/home/bart/.rvm"

  ruby:
    interpreter:  "ruby"
    version:      "2.0.0p247"
    date:         "2013-06-27"
    platform:     "x86_64-linux"
    patchlevel:   "2013-06-27 revision 41674"
    full_version: "ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-linux]"

  homes:
    gem:          "/home/bart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0"
    ruby:         "/home/bart/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247"

  binaries:
    ruby:         "/home/bart/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby"
    irb:          "/home/bart/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/irb"
    gem:          "/home/bart/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/gem"
    rake:         "/home/bart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/bin/rake"

  environment:
    PATH:         "/home/bart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/bin:/home/bart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/bin:/home/bart/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin:/home/bart/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"
    GEM_HOME:     "/home/bart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0"
    GEM_PATH:     "/home/bart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0:/home/bart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global"
    MY_RUBY_HOME: "/home/bart/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247"
    IRBRC:        "/home/bart/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/.irbrc"
    RUBYOPT:      ""
    gemset:       "railstutorial_rails_4_0"
```

Comment: Not sure at all. But can you try to delete your gemfile.lock, restarting server and try again ?

Comment: Hmm... who's bright idea was it to name Gemfile and Gemfile.lock like that? :)  Thank Heaven for git :) still no-workie.  Thanks for the suggestion (adding this step into every try, though).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it.

Many thanks for all the suggestions--trying them helped me keep pushing for different causes.

The clue came when `rails s` (inside the app) produced good results, but hitting apache didn't. Found the [Apache/Passenger setup docs](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#PassengerRuby) where I had missed (noob to RoR, so actually "didn't know to") set the PassengerRuby in the virtual host config.

According to the tutorial I had created the gemset "railstutorial_rails_4_0" in `/home/bart/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0`

in /etc/apache2/mods-available/passenger.conf

```
PassengerRoot /home/bart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/passenger-4.0.19
PassengerDefaultRuby /home/bart/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.0.0-p247/ruby
```

Which was great until `bundle install` put things in the tutorial gemset.

I was missing this in the vhost definition:

```
PassengerRuby /home/bart/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/ruby
```

Restart Apache.

Now it works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

You have `gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.3.2.0'` specified in your Gemfile but have 2.3.2.2 loaded on your machine.  Try uninstalling the gem and re-running the bundle command.

```
bundle exec gem uninstall GEM_NAME
bundle install
```

I ran through this tutorial awhile back as well.  Looking over my code I never specified a version for bootstrap-sass.  You may want to try that as well.

Comment: I actually had both versions installed. `bundle exec gem ...` didn't work, but just `gem uninstall ...` did. Removed all and reinstalled with no version specified. Then I get the same error about multi_json, so I uninstall/reinstall multi_json. Then I get the bootstrap error again. Should I uninstall all gems and start over?

Comment: Yes, now when I comment out the bootstrap-sass line from my Gemfile I get the multi_json error. So, without bootstrap I `gem uninstall multi_json` (yes), `rm Gemfile.lock`, `bundle install` (and it reinstalls multi_json), restart apache and same error: "Could not find multi_json-1.8.1 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)"

Comment: Is this a case where `gem install ...` isn't putting the gems in the gemset? So I tried `bundle exec gem install multi_json` (killed Gemfile.lock, restart apache` and it runs. But doing the same with bootstrap-sass doesn't seem to work. It seems if I do a `bundle install` then I am back where I started...

Comment: The `rails s` server appears to have no issues, but apache/passenger do.